# What are other ways of creating object properties in JS with enumerable set to false by default?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, enumerable

> Enumerable properties are those properties whose internal [[Enumerable]] flag is set to true, which is the default for properties created via simple assignment or via a property initializer (properties defined via Object.defineProperty **and such** default [[Enumerable]] to false).

```
var person = new Object();

//person = {"hair": "red", "eyes": "blue"};    

Object.defineProperty(person, "gender", {value: "male"});
Object.defineProperty(person, "name", {value: "Joe"});

for (var prop in person) {
    console.log(prop + " = " + person[prop]);
}
```

This will produce nothing, not even an error as enumerables are set to false. Uncomment the simple assignment and comment out defineProperty, it will produce

`"hair": "red", "eyes": "blue".`

MDN says "... **and such**", well to me Object.defineProperty is the only way of creating properties with enumarables set to false by default.

PS. I should probably re-word it a bit. When I do new Object() its enumerable attribute is set to false by default, so when I did Object.defineProperty() I didn't touch the enumerable attribute, it is still false. But the enumerable is set to true when you subsequently do a simple assignment.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, using Object.defineProperty is the only way to modify the enumerable flag. Prior to ES5 we had no such mechanism.

Comment: Object.defineProperty() may be the only way to modify the enumerable flag. When I created new Object() its enumerable attributes will be set to false. So when I did defineProperty() I didn't touch the enumerables, they are still false.